# Use variable font to thin larger headings

Tags: typography, font-weight

I remember Microsoft Office 2007 introduced a style of headings that got lighter as the heading size got bigger. Now we can use variable fonts in websites, what about keeping the colour the same, but varying the font weight for each heading to achieve the same effect.

[image]

Is the hierarchy of the document going to remain clear? Is the readability going to better or worse? Does this idea work?

Comment: What you want to do is older than computers, have a look at: [What's with size-specific fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/66815/19174) If this does not fully answer your question, please [edit] it to focus on whatever wasn’t answered.

Comment: *a style of headings that got lighter as the heading size got bigger.* – Do I presume correctly that *lighter* refers to the colour and not the font weight here?